# Having a List<string> where rows can be the same value, how to add a int to make each row unique?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a List where I would like to add an internal counter when several items have the same name.

```
var myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("a");
myList.Add("b");
myList.Add("b");
myList.Add("c");
```

And I want the result to be
a01
b01
b02
c01
after some fancy LINQ stuff.

Any great ideas out there?

Comment: Are the items guaranteed to be in order? Can this happen: `a, b, b, c, a` ? If yes, what should the counter behavior be?

Comment: The order is not important, your example should return a1,b1,b2,c1,a2 Edit: Sorry missunderstod, I can make it in order by sorting if thats an issue.

Comment: That's not an issue, it's just that you could do things differently. I added an answer considering your first description, that code could be slightly simplified in case of sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not saying that's nice, but it's a (mostly) Linq solution:

```
var indexed =   from index in myList.Aggregate(
                    new 
                    { 
                        Counters = new Dictionary<string, int>(), 
                        Items = new List<string>() 
                    }, 
                    (acc, cur) => 
                    { 
                        if (!acc.Counters.ContainsKey(cur))
                            acc.Counters.Add(cur, 0);
                        acc.Counters[cur] = acc.Counters[cur] + 1;
                        acc.Items.Add(cur + acc.Counters[cur]);
                        return acc;
                    }).Items
                select index;
```

The accumulation part is pretty ugly, but it does the job and all inside a Linq computation.

**EDIT**

If the initial list is already sorted, this expression is cleaner (but might be inefficient, you'd have to see how many items you have in your list):

```
var indexed =   from index in myList.Aggregate(
                    new 
                    { 
                        Counter = 0, 
                        Key     = (string)null,
                        Items   = Enumerable.Empty<string>() 
                    }, 
                    (acc, cur) => 
                    {
                        var counter = acc.Key != cur ? 1 : acc.Counter+1;
                        return new 
                        { 
                            Counter = counter,
                            Key     = cur,
                            Items   = acc.Items.Concat(
                                        Enumerable.Repeat(cur + counter, 1))
                        };
                    }).Items
                select index;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the order, there's no amazingly nice way to do this in OOTB LINQ, but you could knock something up like

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWithUniquifier<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> uniquifier)
{
     Dictionary<TSource, int> counter = new Dictionary<TSource, int>();
     foreach(TSource s in source)
     {
         int thisIndex = counter.ContainsKey(s) ? counter[s] : 0;
         counter[s] = thisIndex + 1;
         yield return uniquifier(s, thisIndex);
     }
}
```

just with a better name.

For your example you'd have

```
var result = myList.SelectWithUniquifier((s, i) => s + (i+1).ToString("00"));
```

as the index you get is zero-based.

Comment: You could further extend this with an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` parameter so you could use e.g. `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Could not figure this example out, will look into it a bit deeper though! Looks sleek..

Answer (score 1):

See other answers for some fancy (and pretty confusing) LINQ solutions. If you don't necessarily need to use LINQ:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "b" };

var counter = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    var currVal = myList[i];
    counter.AddOrUpdate(currVal, 1, (value, count) => count + 1);
    myList[i] = currVal + counter[currVal].ToString("00");
}
```

`ConcurrentDictionary` is not needed, you can do the "add or update" thing manually, depending on how you value speed vs code clarity. Either way, in my opinion this is a much more readable and maintainable way to do what you want to do. Don't be scared of ye olde for loop. :)

Of course this could be done as an extension method, or a static method on some utility class etc.

Comment: That will return a1, b2, c1 not a1, b1, b2, c1 unfortunatly

Comment: No? :) Have you tried the code? I get a01, b01, c01, b02. I'm not using the `ConcurrentDictionary` for the result. It's just a counter.

Comment: You are totaly correct, my misstake - was a bit fast when I tried it out!

Comment: @AndersHolmström I agree with you that in this case Linq does not look quite nice :)  but I think it's still important to show ways to solve simple problems with it because one day you might need those in more complex scenarios, where you might have to compose computations and hence loops might not be an option

Comment: @Wasp I agree, and wasn't trying to criticise any of the LINQ answers. I wouldn't have been able to do it any nicer. :) And in general it's also a good LINQ exercise to write/understand something like this. But I also think people can get LINQ-blind and try to do everything through it just because it feels more 'modern'.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way:

```
  var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => x + (i + 1).ToString("00")));
```

Comment: This really should be the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var res =
    myList
        .GroupBy(item => item)
        .Select(item => String.Format("{0}{1}", item.Key, item.Count()));
```

Comment: That will return a1, b2, c1 not a1, b1, b2, c1